# NetworkUsage sample app Showing Error Parsing XML

Tags: android

I run NetworkUsage sample project app on Android Studio, project builds issue free. However, when it runs on my device (NOT emulator), I get an *XmlPullParserException*. I have my phone connected to wifi and assigned correct permissions in manifest. when i do a debug, i trace it all the way to

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
```

that is where it stops. The parser processes the *inputStream* fetching data from

```
private static final String URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=android&sort=newest";
```

for some reason name parameter(in this case "feed") does not equal getName(), in this case **html**, and i dont know where it is getting **html** from. My knowledge on parsing xml and hmtl markup is very very limited and going through the motions of learning this aspect of programming and how it will integrate with future projects. i say this because my question might seem trivial to some. Thanks for the help

```
public class StackOverflowXmlParser {
private static final String ns = null;

// We don't use namespaces

public List<Entry> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private List<Entry> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("entry")) {
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

// This class represents a single entry (post) in the XML feed.
// It includes the data members "title," "link," and "summary."
public static class Entry {....}

// Parses the contents of an entry. If it encounters a title, summary, or link tag, hands them
// off
// to their respective &quot;read&quot; methods for processing. Otherwise, skips the tag.
private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {}

// Processes title tags in the feed.
private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {}

// Processes link tags in the feed.
private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {}

// Processes summary tags in the feed.
private String readSummary(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {}

// For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {}

// Skips tags the parser isn't interested in. Uses depth to handle nested tags. i.e.,
// if the next tag after a START_TAG isn't a matching END_TAG, it keeps going until it
// finds the matching END_TAG (as indicated by the value of "depth" being 0).
private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {}
```

Here is the link to the project/android training section on parsing xml 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: You need to change the scheme on `URL` in that sample from `http` to `https`. What you're getting now is a "this has moved" message, which is why the parser fails. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time.

Comment: @MikeM. works like a charm mate, i wish Stack Overflow had a friend system so i can add you on my friendlist

Comment: Ah, that's good to hear. I just happened to have downloaded that sample a coupla days when somebody else asked something about it, and I still had it hanging around. Btw, I figured that out by reading the `InputStream` passed into the `parse()` method directly into a `String`, and just `Lod`'d it. There are several methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35446009) that you can use to do that on Android without any extra setup. #6 is pretty straightforward and portable. Just so ya know, should you need it in the future. Glad you got it working. Cheers!